# Can we JSON to do search in Azure Cognitive search like Mongo DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cognitive-services, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am working on Cosmos DB SQL API and I want to run JSON formated query strings. In Mongo DB you can run queries like

```
 "$and": [
        {
            "images": {
                "$exists": true
            },
            "$where": "this.something.length > 1"
        },
        {
            "location": "core"
        }
    ]
```

Is there a way to run similar queries in Azure Cognitive search and Cosmos DB?

Answer (score 0):

What is supported for JSON queries in NoSQL for Cosmos DB is [JSON expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/working-with-json#json-expressions) and there is a small sample for [Cosmos DB NoSQL indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb): projections with JSON expressions query:

```
SELECT VALUE { "id":c.id, "Name":c.contact.firstName, "Company":c.company, "_ts":c._ts } FROM c WHERE c._ts >= @HighWaterMark ORDER BY c._ts
```